# ¿Cómo borrar el contenido de un archivo de texto en python?

Tags: python, bucle-for

En `python` estoy realizando un proyecto en el que cada vez que mi programa corra debo asegurarme que cierto archivo de texto esté vacío por lo que se me ocurrió que cada vez que inicie el programa borre todo el contenido dentro del mismo. Había pensado en recorrer poner una `función` donde recorra línea por línea y vaya substituyendo cualquier caractér que encuentre y lo vuelva un `""`. 
¿Alguien podría darme una mejor idea de como hacerlo?

***Nota: mi programa va a escribir cierto contenido dentro del archivo de que debería estar vació. Entonces deseo que antes de grabar el contenido nuevo, se borre el viejo. Ya una vez borrado todo el contenido, el programa debería escribir los nuevos datos.

Comment: Hola @Androso, te recomiendo poner algo de codigo para saber exacatmente que buscas y tu pregunta no sea cerrada. Te sugiero leer este apartadao para mejorar tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Saludos

Comment: Hoa Androso, tu programa va simplemente a sobrescribir el archivo? Porque en ese caso simplemente debes abrirlo en modo escritura (`w` o `wb`) y no en modo `a` o `r+` por ejemplo ¿o cuál es la razón exacta por la que el archivo debe estar vacío?

Comment: @FJSevilla fijate que mi programa va a escribir cierto contenido dentro del archivo de que deberia estar vacio. Entonces deseo que antes de grabar el contenido nuevo, se borre el viejo. Ya una vez borrado todo el contenido, el programa deberia escribir los nuevos datos

Comment: Hola de nuevo, no debes usar las respuestas para agregar información o constestar a comentarios, lo mejor es que uses el botón editar que hay debajo de la pregunta y lo agregues a ella. ¿Como abres el archivo para escribir en el? Como comento arriba si abres en modo w o wb el archivo se trunca automáticamente antes de escribir, por lo que tu problema quedaría resuelto. Agrega el código en el que abres y escribes en el fichero a la pregunta ¿Escribes manualmente en el o le pasas el fichero a alguna función de un módulo o framework externo, por lo que no controlas como se abre el archivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no tener que crear un bucle si solo lo vas a abrir para escribir algo en el se abre en modo 'w'. Es decir:

```
archivo = open('archivo.txt','w')
archivo.write('Escribes el contenido')
archivo.close() #Cierras el archivo.
```

Si lo haces así la función open borra el contenido al abrirlo. Si quieres mantener el contenido y continuar agregando al texto debes abrirlo en modo 'w+'.